# Using the correct pack:// URI Format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF class Library, containing a Folder "Images" that contains an Image.
In a WPF application I wont to refer to the image in that Folder using

```
<Image Name="image" Grid.Row="0" Source="pack://application:,,,/ImageService.dll;Component/Images/image.jpg"/>
```

The image ist marked as "Ressource" and I also added it to the resources of the class library Project. After some searching I found out, that I have to copy the dll into the exe directory.

During designtime the image is displayed correctly. After launching the executable the `source` property of the image is null. No error message and no hints in the output window.

It seems, that the Format of the pack uri is incorrect, so the runtime refers to a wrong place. Is there a way to specify the assembly name relative to the executable, using "....\AssemblyName.dll" or absolute to file systems root.

Unfortunately I cannot assign the imagesource via code, because all the content goes through XAMLWriter - XAMLReader construct from the dll to the executing assembly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to copy image to output directory. Make sure you mark the **`Build Action`** as **`Resource`** and set **`Copy to Output Directory`** to **`false`**.

Also, you can skip assembly name in pack URI in case XAML and image resides in same assembly. In case they resides in different assembly, you have to give only assembly name (**remove dll from path**).

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/ImageService;Component/Images/image.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing dll from path worked.
But only if the dll is in the same folder as the executable. I have to refer the image in the dll, that is located elsewhere. The executing assembly rresides in 

[PROJECTFOLDER]\ImageConsumer\bin\debug

the assembly containing the image resides in

[PROJECTFOLDER]\ImageService\bin\debug

So i Need something like '..\..\..\ImageService\bin\debug\ImageService.dll'.

Comment: But only if the dll is in the same folder as the executable. I have to refer the image in the dll, that is located elsewhere. The executing assembly rresides in 

[PROJECTFOLDER]\ImageConsumer\bin\debug

the assembly containing the image resides in

[PROJECTFOLDER]\ImageService\bin\debug

So i need something like '..\..\..\ImageService\bin\debug\ImageService.dll'. Or an absolute path.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Ideally that assembly should be copied to executable path. Wasn't `ImageService` part of your solution? All referenced assemblies gets copied to output path automatically.

Comment: Yes in this case the 'ImageService' is part of the solution (Which is at current stage an text - exe). 

Generally the 'ImageService' is an extension to an existing project, that dynamically loads dlls, that create xaml code an return that to the main program. That loads and displays the generated XAML code. My extension needs to refer to images, the main application has no clue about it. So I need to do a "backward reference" to the images that live in the dll. Unfortunately in the dll I can not rely on a specific fixed position. but ist possibible to parameterize that.

Comment: I don't think that's possible from XAML. Try using the converter which will return path using some calculation and bind converter to XAML. Also you can read more about how to use [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for fonts. I'm trying with `pack://application:,,,/MyDLL;Component/Resources/#FontName`. Font file (ttf) is included in `MyDLL` as Resource with `Do not copy` option. Font seems to work fine from within the DLL but not from the main EXE assembly.

Comment: When you remove the assembly name, you also need to remove the `;Component/` part. The URI then looks like: `pack://application:,,,/Images/image.jpg`. With this kind of URI, WPF takes the assembly returned by `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` but you can override this by setting the property `System.Windows.Application.ResourceAssembly`.