# Pack URI for an Aliased Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a project with a `ResourceDictionary` defined in a XAML file. This project uses an aliased assembly name by adding the following code to the AssemblyInfo.cs file

`[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.myproject.com/xaml/wpf", "MyNameSpace.Wpf")]`

A parent project has a reference to this project. I can import the child project's namespace into XAML using the following syntax

`xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.myproject.com/xaml/wpf"`

In that parent project, I need access to the `ResourceDictionary` in the child project. I've attempted to use Pack URIs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx

The documentation makes it pretty clear how to use Pack URIs to access assemblies by name explicitly. It does not however make it clear if it's possible with an aliased assembly. For example, I've tried:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,http:,,schemas.myproject.com,xaml,wpf;component/Source/DictionaryFile.xaml"/>`

The resulting error message is "The URI prefix is not recognized". Is there special Pack URI syntax for accomplishing this? And to note, the child assembly must use this alias. Both projects are shared, and the actual child assembly name may vary. Using the alias allows me to abstract the difference in naming away.

Comment: There may be something here that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171601/using-the-correct-pack-uri-format?rq=1