# Using pack Uri with resource from a library

Tags: wpf

Support Resource loading in a library, where you have no control over the calling executable.
I do not wish to load files from disk.

How can I fix the ConsoleApp2 code so it supports the described scenario?

Based on the [Pack Uri documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf), I was able to do this:

### What works

- FontLibrary, a **Class Library** containing only font files with `Build Action: Resource`
- ConsoleApp1, **Console Application** referencing this FontLibrary.

#### ConsoleApp1 code

Add reference to `WindowsBase` runtime assembly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Workaround to register pack://application Uri format
        var notUsedButNeeded  = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;

        var fontFamilies = System.Windows.Media.Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "/FontLibrary;Component/");

        // This correctly lists the font families contained in the font library
        Console.WriteLine("Number of font families: " + fontFamilies.Count);
    }
}
```

### What doesn't work:

Exception message is

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'
```

- LogicLibrary, a **Class Library** referecing FontLibrary
- FontLibrary, a **Class Library** containing only font files with `Build Action: Resource`
- ConsoleApp2, a **Console Application** referencing LogicLibrary. This represents any consumer of the LogicLibrary, and I cannot add references from this library to the font library, only call LogicLibrary.

#### ConsoleApp2 code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new FontLoader().Load();
    }
}
```

#### LogicLibrary code

```
public class FontLoader
{
    public void Load()
    {
        // Workaround to register pack://application Uri format
        var notUsedButNeeded  = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;

         // Raises exception when called from ConsoleApp2, since the APPLICATION = the ConsoleApp2 does not reference the font library.
        var fontFamilies = System.Windows.Media.Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "/FontLibrary;Component/");

        Console.WriteLine("Number of font families: " + fontFamilies.Count);
    }
}
```

### Similar questions:

[Using the correct pack:// URI Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171601/using-the-correct-pack-uri-format)

Comment: The `GetFontFamilies()` in the `FontLoader.Load()` method can't find the `FontLibrary` because of the Uri() describes assembly location related to the  `AppDomain.BaseDirectory`. Therefore you application will locate the `FontLibrary` if you will copy it to the same directory as the `ConsoleApp2` application is.

Comment: What is the `FontLibrary` location relative to the `ConsoleApp2`? They are located in the same directory? Or are there any restrictions on the location of the `FontLibrary`? Can the `FontLibrary` be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)?"